# Postman visualize XML data

Tags: xml, postman

I have an endpoint that returns an body as XML content. The response looks like this:

```
<Report xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Data>PCEtLSB3aW5kd2F</Data>
</Report>
```

The Data field contains base64 and I would like to use the Postman vizualiser to be able to show the file. Apparently there are no good ways to show pdf files, but at least I can add a link so a user can download the file and then open it. Now the issue I am having is that I cannot seem to access this data field from within the Test code.

```
var template = `
    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
            <th>Save to file system</th>
        </tr>
        
        {{#each response}}
            <tr>
                <td><p>{{response}}</p></td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
`;

pm.visualizer.set(template, {
    response: xml2Json(pm.response.text())
});

console.log(xml2Json(pm.response.text()))
```

When I check the console, it looks as if the xml body is parsed to an json object correctly. However, if I try to use response in the template above, it is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need to loop through anything here so just changing it to this should show that `Data` value:

```js
var template = `
    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
            <th>Save to file system</th>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td><p>{{response.Report.Data}}</p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
`;

pm.visualizer.set(template, {
    response: xml2Json(pm.response.text())
});
```